# Reloading page in chrome messes up gradient

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, gradient

I have a page where the header is a gradient and on first load everything looks perfectly fine. When I refresh the page the gradient gets messed up and it seems like it puts in 2 gradients (1 really small) example below:

[image]

The first one is after a reload and the second is on first hitting the page.

The small gradient on top that I don't want is the same height as the padding in that div.

I've also noticed that imgs get resized on reloads like this as well and I've solved that by setting the height in css. I can't set the height in css because the height should be dynamic.

Can anyone explain to me why this might be happening and a way to solve it? I would really prefer a non-javascript solution because I already know how I might solve using jquery.

Some Code:

HTML:

```
<header>
      <a id="settings-gear" href="#"><img src="/img/gear.png"> &nbsp;</a>
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo" alt="logo">
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0F7F7 0%,#B8D9DD 100%);
    max-height: 122px;
    padding: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

header #logo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header #settings-gear img {
    height: 33px;
}
```

Comment: can you pst a link to the offending URL for inspection?

Comment: Can you post some code or a URL, thanks!

Comment: A link to a live page might be needed in this case, or a demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid a link is not possible. And I tried creating a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's difficult if we can't see a link or example, but the first think that comes to my mind is set the background as image and tell it to fit only the content with `background-origin:content-box;`. Try put that line into the header properties, and hope it helps. Note that the `background-origin` property don't work in IE 5, 6, 7 or 8...

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from using images for my gradients. I have my reasons but thanks for your feedback.